# How do I manually focus my Nikon P520?

Tags: nikon, focus, manual-focus, coolpix, infinity-focus

Can I manually focus a Nikon P520, and can I set infinity as well? I've looked at the manual settings and I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can manually focus the P520. The instructions are on page 2 of the reference section in the manual, at the back. The screen shot in the manual shows an infinity symbol, so I imagine it is possible to focus to infinity as well.